# How to customize LayeredGraphPlot?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

The following graph is a revised version of @kglr's code developed few years ago.

```
ClearAll[edges, vertices, groups, colors, options];
vertices = {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"FNS\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\" \",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"issue\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"DATA\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"MODEL\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"KNOWLEDGE\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"POLICY\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)"};
groups = {{"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"FNS\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\" \",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"issue\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)"}, {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"DATA\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"MODEL\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"KNOWLEDGE\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)"}, {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"POLICY\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)"}};
colors = 
  Flatten@MapThread[
    Thread@*Rule, {groups, {LightGray, LightBlue, Red}}];
edges = {
   Style[Labeled["\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"FNS\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\" \",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"issue\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)" -> "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"DATA\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", "data domain"], Blue, 
    13, Thick],
   Style[Labeled["\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"DATA\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)" -> "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"MODEL\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", "flows into"], Blue, 
    13, Thick],
   Style[Labeled["\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"MODEL\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)" -> "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"KNOWLEDGE\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", "generates"], Blue,
     13, Thick], Style[Labeled["\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"KNOWLEDGE\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)" -> "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"POLICY\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", 
     "used in policy design"], Blue, 13, Thick], 
   Style[Labeled["\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"POLICY\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)" -> "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"DATA\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", "feedback to adjust"], 
    Dashed, Red, 13, Thick], Style[Labeled["\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"POLICY\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)" -> "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"MODEL\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", "feedback to adjust"], 
    Dashed, Red, 13, Thick]};

options = {
   VertexLabels -> {_ -> Placed[Automatic, Center]}, 
   VertexShapeFunction -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"FNS\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\" \",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"issue\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)" -> "Square", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"POLICY\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)" -> "ConcaveHexagon"},
   VertexStyle -> colors,
   VertexSize -> Large,
   ImageSize -> 600,
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[14, Background -> White]
   };
LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Left, options]
```

While customizing it for my needs,I could not produce what I want to. The following figure shows an incomplete graph which I like to revise it in the following ways:

1. The graph should be upside down;
2. Red element `Policy` should be on the right hand side at the level of `Knowledge`;

Thanks very much for your support.

[image]

Comment: Edit your question to remove all of the irrelevant formatting.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: I am trying to put the code in a readable format, but none of the formats are giving me a nice code appearance. I used traditional form, input form, standard form, code, etc. This started to happen after updating my MMA version to 13.1. Do you know the right format?

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: I edited the question and the graph looks much better than previous one.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: `LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Right, options]` answers to my 1st question. If I can have a graph where `FNS issue` goes from `Left` to `Right`, then the second question will be solved also.

Comment: @TugrulTemel if I understand correctly, the only issue after `LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Right, options]` is the orientation of the arrow connecting `FNS issue` and `DATA`, right?

Comment: @bmf: Not only the arrow orientation but also the position of the box "FNS issue". This box should be at the top-left of the figure, and the arrow should be from this box to DATA. Bob's answer was half-way through.

Comment: @TugrulTemel thanks for the clarification. Just to make sure, is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Bms.png) what you want?

Comment: @bmf: The arrow from "FNS issue" box should be an outgoing arrow. The rest is perfect.

Comment: @TugrulTemel thanks for the confirmation. Perhaps something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRGrW.png) is closer to what you had in mind? With an extra outgoing arrow from `FNS issue`

Comment: @bmf: Thanks for your efforts. I think I could not explain myself better. I only wanted to reverse the direction of the arrow from "FNS issue" box to DATA, nothing more. Your addition of a new arrow from FNS issue box is not necessary.

Comment: @TugrulTemel ok I see now what the objective was. I will give it a go

Comment: @bmf: In the original question above, the arrow from FNS issue box to DATA is correct.

Comment: @bmf: if you have time to put your effort as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @TugrulTemel unfortunately I cannot do the final step...

Comment: bmp: no problem at all. If you can reverse the direction of the arrow, that is sufficient.

Comment: If you are going to make a single small diagram, with strict requirements on how it should look, it will be much easier to do it with a proper diagramming software. I can recommend yEd. You can even export the graph from Mathematica and import to yEd, then edit it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** make sure to read original version for some explanations.

```
ClearAll[edges, vertices, groups, colors, options];
```

The following chunk of code

```
vertices = {Style["FNS issue", FontWeight -> Bold], 
   Style["DATA", FontWeight -> Bold], 
   Style["MODEL", FontWeight -> Bold], 
   Style["KNOWLEDGE", FontWeight -> Bold], 
   Style["POLICY", FontWeight -> Bold]};
groups = {{Style["FNS issue", FontWeight -> Bold]}, {Style["DATA", 
     FontWeight -> Bold], Style["MODEL", FontWeight -> Bold], 
    Style["KNOWLEDGE", FontWeight -> Bold]}, {Style["POLICY", 
     FontWeight -> Bold]}};
colors = 
  Flatten@MapThread[
    Thread@*Rule, {groups, {LightGray, LightBlue, Red}}];
e[1] = Style[
   Labeled[Style["DATA", FontWeight -> Bold] -> 
     Style["FNS issue", FontWeight -> Bold], "data domain"], Blue, 13,
    Thick];
e[2] = Style[
   Labeled[Style["DATA", FontWeight -> Bold] -> 
     Style["MODEL", FontWeight -> Bold], "flows into"], Blue, 13, 
   Thick];
e[3] = Style[
   Labeled[Style["MODEL", FontWeight -> Bold] -> 
     Style["KNOWLEDGE", FontWeight -> Bold], "generates"], Blue, 13, 
   Thick];
e[4] = Style[
   Labeled[
    Style["KNOWLEDGE", FontWeight -> Bold] -> 
     Style["POLICY", FontWeight -> Bold], "used in policy design"], 
   Blue, 13, Thick];
e[5] = Style[
   Labeled[
    Style["POLICY", FontWeight -> Bold] -> 
     Style["DATA", FontWeight -> Bold], "feedback to adjust"], Dashed,
    Red, 13, Thick];
e[6] = Style[
   Labeled[Style["POLICY", FontWeight -> Bold] -> 
     Style["MODEL", FontWeight -> Bold], "feedback to adjust"], 
   Dashed, Red, 13, Thick];
edges = Table[e[xx], {xx, 1, 6}];
options = {
   VertexLabels -> {_ -> Placed[Automatic, Center]},
   VertexShapeFunction -> {Style["FNS issue", FontWeight -> Bold] -> 
      "Square", 
     Style["POLICY", FontWeight -> Bold] -> "ConcaveHexagon"}, 
   VertexStyle -> colors, VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> 600, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[14, Background -> White]};
new2 = SetProperty[{Graph[
     edges], (Style["DATA", FontWeight -> Bold] -> 
      Style["FNS issue", FontWeight -> Bold])}, 
   EdgeStyle -> {Arrowheads[{{-.02, .01}}]}];
Graph[new2, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
   "Orientation" -> Right}, options]
```

returns

> [image: graph]

**Original version:** This is not an answer, but perhaps some helpful to get you going. At least, this is my intention. Also, I am taking into account the comments by the author of the OP

As you will see, I am leaving some final formatting to you, as I am a bit swamped. Sorry...

First of all, we can simplify the picture to the bare essentials, and fix the formatting options at the end.

I believe that the following does the trick

```
vertices = {"fns issue", "data", "model", "knowledge", "policy"};
groups = {{"fns issue"}, {"data", "model", "knowledge"}, {"policy"}};
colors = 
  Flatten@MapThread[
    Thread@*Rule, {groups, {LightGray, LightBlue, Red}}];
options = {
   VertexLabels -> {_ -> Placed[Automatic, Center]},
   VertexShapeFunction -> {"fns issue" -> "Square", 
     "policy" -> "ConcaveHexagon"}, VertexStyle -> colors, 
   VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> 600, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[14, Background -> White]};
edges = {"data" -> "fns issue", "data" -> "model", 
   "model" -> "knowledge", "knowledge" -> "policy", 
   "policy" -> "data", "policy" -> "model"};
```

> [image: simplegraph]

The final step is to reverse the arrow that connects `fns issue` and `data`

You should have a look at the following:

```
GraphicsRow@{Graph[edges], 
  new1 = SetProperty[{Graph[edges], ("data" -> "fns issue")}, 
    EdgeShapeFunction -> (Arrow@Reverse@# &)], 
  new2 = SetProperty[{Graph[edges], ("data" -> "fns issue")}, 
    EdgeStyle -> {Arrowheads[{{-.1, .01}}]}]}
```

[image: graphicsrow]

And then one can imagine doing something like

```
new2 = SetProperty[{Graph[edges], ("data" -> "fns issue")}, 
   EdgeStyle -> {Arrowheads[{{-.02, .01}}]}];
Graph[new2, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
   "Orientation" -> Right}, options]
```

[image: final]

As far as I can tell, it has the right orientation and the arrows are pointing to the right directions.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for all your efforts and time. This is perfect!

Comment: @TugrulTemel glad I was able to help :-)